# XQuery: Returning more than one element

Tags: xml, xquery

The following is the DTD describing the structure of the XML I am working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE bib [
<!ELEMENT bib (book+,magazine*)>
<!ELEMENT book (title,author+,publisher,editor?,price)>
<!ELEMENT magazine (title,publisher,editor+)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (last,first)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT editor (last, first,affiliation)>
<!ELEMENT price ((#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT last (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT first (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT affiliation (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST book year CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
```

I have to write an XQuery to return all books or magazines where Mr. Weikum is one of the editors.

I am having a problem in determining how to return book or magazine. This is what I can come up with:

```
for $x in document(“bib.xml”)/bib
where $x/book/editor/lastname = “Weikum” or $x/magazine/editor/lastname = “Weikum”
return <result></result>
```

But this is not achieving my desired result.  How can I return the book or magazine element? Should I just say `return $x`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to return books and magazines with an editor whose last name is 'Weikum' would be

```
//editor[lastname='Weikum']/..
```

Or, if you prefer a FLWOR expression, yes, you can just say `return $x`, if $x is bound to what you want to return.  That's not true in your sketch, however:  you say you want to return the book or magazine, but you have bound $x to the `bib` element.  You want something more like this:

```
for $x in document('bib.xml')/bib/*
where $x/editor/lastname='Weikum'
return $x
```

In these two formulations I am exploiting the fact that only books and magazines have children named `editor`, and that only books and magazines appear as children of `bib`.  In a more complicated DTD, you might need more complex expressions if you needed to filter out pamphlets, standards, and blog posts in order to get *just* books and magazines ...

Comment: thnx alot...this really helps. u first expression is an xpath right? not an xquery?

Comment: Strictly speaking, XQuery is a superset of XPath, so the first expression is both valid XPath and XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//*[self::book or self::magazine][editor[lastname eq 'Weikum']]
```

From the DTD it is clear that only a `book` or a `magazine` can have a child `editor`.

**If the document is validated successfully against this DTD, then the expression can be simpler:**

```
//*[editor[lastname eq 'Weikum']]
```

**If we believe the DTD, a `book` or a `magazine` must be a child of the top element of the XML document**.

This allows us to provide a potentially more efficient expression:

```
/*/*[editor[lastname eq 'Weikum']]
```